# Cannot convert from 'cli::array<Type> ^' to 'cli::array<Type> ^'

Tags: struct, c++-cli

C++ CLR, in Visual Studio 2010 (C++).

I have this struct:

```
value struct Triangle{
    static array<int>^ v = gcnew array<int>(3);
    static array<int>^ t = gcnew array<int>(3);
    static array<int>^ n = gcnew array<int>(3);
};
```

and I declare the following in "private" section of my class:

```
static array<Triangle^>^ triangles = gcnew array<Triangle>(MAX_POLYGONS);
```

I get this error and I have no idea what it means (because it seems to contradict itself):

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'cli::array<Type> ^' to 'cli::array<Type> ^'
         with
         [
             Type=Triangle
         ]
```

Evidently it doesn't like the struct. Should I be using ref instead of value? That produces a lot of pointers. Any push into the correct direction would be appreciated.

Comment: For what it's worth, your Triangle struct contains 3 reference types. If you're concerned about creating objects on the heap and how you might be affecting the garbage collector, consider making that a value type, either with another struct or by declaring 9 integers directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have an extra hat (^) in your statement.  It should read:

```
static array<Triangle>^ triangles = gcnew array<Triangle>(MAX_POLYGONS);
```

Comment: Alright, I fixed that, and used Dave's suggestion as well. But I have another problem now, maybe someone can help. I am making two instances of the same "Model" class within which I have the above Triangle. Each instance should have its own Triangle. The problem is, they change each other's arrays. It seems like the pointers point to the same location? I'm not sure how that's possible.

Comment: Sounds like another question--it would be better to post a new question with code.

Comment: The "static" keyword was, well, key in solving that problem. All is well, thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually for me, I had to use both hats: array<Triangle^>^ triangles. But I was also calling a method from C# generated DLL to retrieve those triangles.